# Expand if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code snippet below was created to have hide or show dropdowns depending on what is selected.  In the case below:

```
**TRANSLATION**
If modelyear <= 67
And assyplant=bf
Or modelyear >=68 
then display the following dropdowns etc.
```

What I would like is to expand on this stating the following:

```
If modelyear <=67
And assyplant =bf
OR 
modelyear <=67
And assyplant =bc
Or modelyear >=68 then display the following dropdowns etc etc etc.
```

Already have the following working code:

```
// model_year + assy_plant logic
                if (thisField == 'model_year' || thisField == 'assy_plant') {
                    var modelYear = parseInt($('#model_year').children('option:selected').text());
                    if (isNaN(modelYear)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var assyPlant = $('#assy_plant').children('option:selected').text();

                    $('tr#row6').css('display', 'none');
                    $('tr#row7').css('display', 'none');
                    $('tr#row6 select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('tr#row7 select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    if (((modelYear <= 67 && assyPlant.toLowerCase()) == 'bf') 
                    || modelYear >=   68) {
                        $('tr#row6').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row6 select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('tr#row7').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row7 select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                }
```

It is likely that I will have to add additional assyplant values in the future.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**jQuery.inArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) to check if `assyplant` is one of the possible values.

```
var assyplants = ['bf', 'bc']; // Expandable list of assyPlant values to check for

if ((model_year <= 67 && jQuery.inArray(assyPlant.toLowerCase(), assyplants)!==-1) 
     || model_year >= 68) 
{ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention the possibility of adding additional assyplant values, I suggest storing all possibilities in an array, then using the array.some() method

```
var poss_values = ['bf', 'bc']; 

var check_assy = poss_values.some(function(val){
        return assyPlant.toLowerCase() === val;
    })
if ((modelYear <= 67 && check_assy) || modelYear >=   68) {
        $('tr#row6').css('display', 'table-row');
        $('tr#row6 select').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
                $('tr#row7').css('display', 'table-row');
                $('tr#row7 select').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (((modelYear <= 67 && assyPlant.toLowerCase()) == 'bf') 
                    || modelYear >=   68) {
                        $('tr#row6').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row6 select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    } 
 else if (((modelYear <= 67 && assyPlant.toLowerCase()) == 'bc') 
                    || modelYear >=   68) {
                        $('tr#row6').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row6 select').removeAttr('disabled');


                    } else {
                        $('tr#row7').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row7 select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                }

                else {
                        $('tr#row7').css('display', 'table-row');
                        $('tr#row7 select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                }
```

I added a else if statement so you can add more assyPlant's. Of course you have to assign them a new var like this: `var values =['bf',  'bc'];`